# Convert web service call to a dictionary object

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a web service that I am calling which take a string, and returns a list of strings as an object[].

I want to covert this to a Dictionary> object.  I'm currently using something like this:

```
foreach (string role in allRoles)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> allActionsForRole = 
        lifeRay.getRoleActions(role)
        .ToDictionary<string, List<string>>(role, x => x.ToString());
}
```

It doesn't like the "role" field.

How should I write this?

I'm assuming I could write it somehow to even remove the foreach, right?

Comment: `"It doesn't like the "role" field` - in what way? What errors?

Comment: "has some invalid arguments"

I'm assuming because "role" is not actually  part of the inferred linq select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> allActionsForRole = 
    lifeRay.getRoleActions(role)
    .ToDictionary<string, List<string>>(() => role, x => x.ToString());
```

The method expects two `Func` delegates - so you can provide a "dummy" one for the key.